# Trying to test out sending emails with python and am hitting a snag off the bat

Tags: python, smtp, gmail-api, smtplib

When I click run nothing happens, no errors, nothing. After a min I click stop and get a "KeyboardInterrupt error" but nothing is sent and nothing is received. Here is my code:

```
import smtplib

my_email = "myemail@gmail.com"
password = "Password_i_got_from_gmail_setting_up_an_appPassword"
connection = smtplib.SMTP("smtp.gmail.com")
connection.starttls()
connection.login(user=my_email, password=password)
connection.sendmail(from_addr=my_email, to_addrs="another_email@gmail.com", msg="Hello")
connection.close()
```

what am I doing wrong? UPDATE: after watching a couple videos I made the following adjustments but the same problem remains:

```
import smtplib
import ssl
from email.message import EmailMessage

smtp_server = "smtp.gmail.com"
sender_email = "myemail@gmail.com"
receiver_email = "another_email@gmailcom"
password = "passwordfromgoogleapppasswords"
subject = 'testing'

body = """\
Hi there
This message is sent from Python.
"""

em = EmailMessage()
em['From'] = sender_email
em['To'] = receiver_email
em['Subject'] = subject
em.set_content(body)
context = ssl.create_default_context()
with smtplib.SMTP_SSL('smtp.gmail.com', 1111, context=context) 
as smtp:
     smtp.login(sender_email, password)
     smtp.sendmail(sender_email, receiver_email, em.as_string())
```

now it times out after a couple of min

Comment: Add print statements so you can see where it's getting stuck.

Comment: it does the same thing (runs forever and doesnt do anything) if a print statement is added after this line: "connection = smtplib.SMTP("smtp.gmail.com")"

Comment: It sounds like something is blocking your connection to the SMTP server.

Comment: I set up 2 step verification, created the app password...what other things do I need to do?

Comment: It looks like a network block, nothing to do with authentication.

Comment: Can you do `telnet smtp.gmail.com 587` from the machine?

Comment: I am sorry I am not great at python (trying to learn) where would I put that?

Comment: You do that by hand from a terminal window.

Comment: Ok... it says "command not found: telnet"

Comment: Are you able to send mail through Gmail using a mail client on that machine?

Comment: I have not tried that...its a email I created just to do tests with and try to figure out how to send emails using python, so its not connected to any mail clients...

Comment: You can also try using a packet capture tool while the script is running, to see if it's able to connect to the server.

Comment: What do you recomend?

Comment: It depends on what the problem is. It doesn't seem like a programming problem, you might need to make changes in a firewall. If you're using a hosting service, they may block sending email to keep spammers out.

Comment: Would that explain why I am now getting this error? ssl.SSLCertVerificationError: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:997)

Comment: No, I don't think that's related. I think that may be coming from `ssl.create_default_context()`, but you'd have to show the traceback.

Comment: I figured it out, posted the solution below, it was stupid simple just had to import and use certifi

Answer (score 0):

```
import smtplib, ssl

port = 587  # For starttls
smtp_server = "smtp.gmail.com"
sender_email = "myemail@gmail.com"  # Enter your address
receiver_email = "another_email@gmail.com"  # Enter receiver address
password = input("Type your password and press enter: ")
message = """\
Subject: Hi there

This message is sent from Python."""

context = ssl.create_default_context()
with smtplib.SMTP_SSL(smtp_server, port, context=context) as server:
    server.login(sender_email, password)
    server.sendmail(sender_email, receiver_email, message)
```

Try using this, adding the port and creating a context should help.

Comment: Thank you, getting this error with that code: ssl.SSLError: [SSL: WRONG_VERSION_NUMBER] wrong version number (_ssl.c:997)

Comment: Ok now I am getting this error: ssl.SSLCertVerificationError: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:997)

Answer (score 0):

The problem was I needed to have the certification to use SMTP and SSL, here is the code that I found that worked basically I imported and used certifi:

```
import smtplib
import ssl
from email.message import EmailMessage
##import certifi##


smtp_server = "smtp.gmail.com"
sender_email = "my_email"
receiver_email = "anotheremail"
password = "password"
subject = 'Check this out'

body = """\
Hi there
This message is sent from Python.
"""

em = EmailMessage()
em['From'] = sender_email
em['To'] = receiver_email
em['Subject'] = subject
em.set_content(body)


context = ssl.create_default_context(##cafile=certifi.where()##)
with smtplib.SMTP_SSL('smtp.gmail.com', 465, context=context) as smtp:
    smtp.login(sender_email, password)
    smtp.sendmail(sender_email, receiver_email, em.as_string())
```

Comment: Highlighting doesn't work in code blocks. Remove the `**`, since that would be legitimate Python syntax and it doesn't actually work here.

Comment: You can use comments to show where you changed.

Comment: Using `##` has the same issue; those are also legitimate python syntax used for adding comments. It would be better to move them to the end of the line like this: `import certifi # I added this line`.